# Pass value to command / Create custom buttoms with media9

Tags: media9, multimedia, video, interaction, button

I am quite a newby when it comes to defining custom methods/macros in `LaTeX`. My MWE looks like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{myCounter}
\setcounter{myCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\countCounter}[1]{\addtocounter{myCounter}{\advance #1 by 1}\value{myCounter}}
\newcommand{\returnCounter}[1]{\ifnum #1=1 0 \else {\ifnum #1=2 5 \else \relax \fi} \fi}

\begin{document}

    %\returnCounter{\countCounter{0}}
    \addtocounter{myCounter}{1}
    \returnCounter{\value{myCounter}}

\end{document}
```

What I basically want to do, is to

- increase my counter `myCounter` by some number defined in `\countCounter`
- use that new counter value for further calculations in `\returnCounter`

Normally, I would just successively execute these operations (like in the example), however, I want to pass the result as an argument to an external package. For that reason, I tried to pass the result of `\countCounter` to `\returnCounter` (commented in the example) but that doesn't work. If, of course, `\countCounter` would exclusively return a value, then it would work. Therefore my question is: How does one return values while performing operations inside the same command like `\countCounter`? Thanks!

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, this approach doesn't work; therefore I will reformulate my problem:

My use case is the inclusion of a .mp4-video into the pdf. I want to have two buttons, `forward` and `backward`, which jump to the next/last scene of my video. In an MWE, it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

    \includemedia[
    label=testvideo,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=test.mp4,
    %addresource=test2.mp4,
    flashvars={source=test.mp4},
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
    \mediabutton[overface=mouse-over text]{\fbox{\strut backward}}
    %\mediabutton[overface=mouse-over text, mediacommand=testvideo:Play(\returnTime{\countVideo{0}}),
    %   jsaction=testvideo:{
    %       try{app.clearTimeOut(tout)}catch(e){} % kill pending timers
    %       var tout=app.setTimeOut('annotRM.myvideo.callAS("pause")', 2000);}
    %   ]{\fbox{\strut forward}}

\end{document}
```

The important thing is the commented code: The idea was to have a function passed to `Play()` that

1. counts to which scene the jump takes place
2. returns the correct time stamp.

Additionally, I wanted to have this `jsaction`-method, to automatically stop the video some seconds after certain jumps.

Has anyone an idea, how this could be achieved?

Comment: Returning values isn't really possible in LaTeX, you can only let something expand to something. Some operations aren't expandable though (at least not in TeX's mouth), like for example setting a counter. Also your definition of `\countCounter` seems wrong, there shouldn't be an `\advance` in the argument of `\addtocounter`, I think what you want is `\newcommand\countCounter[1]{\addtocounter{myCounter}{#1}\value{myCounter}`. But this wouldn't return a value, as that is not really possible. So the uncommented lines are the ones which work, and there is no way to make the other line work.

Comment: So, `\returnCounter` either returns `0` or `5` or `\relax`. Is this also your eventual use-case? That won't work since `\relax` isn't something you can perform calculations with.

Comment: Thanks so far. My use case is the following: I want to implement a forward/backward button with the media9 package which jumps to predefined time stamps. The `\returnCounter` is supposed to pass the time stamps to the mediabutton as argument; the `\countCounter` increases or decreases the counter (or leaves it equal if max/min values are reached), which stands for 1-x time stamps in the video.

Comment: @UltimateTrick It would be better if you showed a minimal example with the buttons so that we can work on the counters. `\addtocounter{myCounter}{\advance #1 by 1}` is wrong though. `\addtocounter` uses `\advance` internally, so you should use either `\addtocounter{myCounter}{<some amount>}` or `\advance\c@myCounter by <some amount>`.

Comment: Alright, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right you want two buttons that allow you to fast forward and backward between predefined sections of the video and another button that plays only the current video section and then pauses:

[image]

In order to write JavaScript actions for the media buttons we make use of some ActionScript (Flash) methods of `VPlayer.swf` that are exposed to the JavaScript engine of Acrobat Reader. These methods are documented in [Table 6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#table.6) of the `media9` manual.

In order to seek properly within the video, it must be encoded with a sufficient number of key frames. If necessary, use the following command line to re-encode an existing video. It inserts a key frame every second into a video that plays at 30 frames per second:

```
ffmpeg -i orig-video.mp4 -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"-c:v libx264 -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p-g 30 -r 30 new-video.mp4
```

Before compiling the present example, download this [`example-movie.mp4`](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/mp4/example-movie.mp4) into the working directory. It is a re-encoded version of the video contained in the `mwe` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% these are the scene starting times in seconds
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\sceneStarts{0,10,30,40,55}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\includemedia[
  width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.45\linewidth, %16:9
  label=testvideo,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext, %right-click menu of VPlayer.swf
  addresource=example-movie.mp4,
  flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4},
]{}{VPlayer.swf}\\[3pt]
\noindent%
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("pause");
    try{app.clearInterval(timer);}catch(e){}
    var sceneStarts = [\sceneStarts];
    var tCur=annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("currentTime");
    for(var idx=0; idx < sceneStarts.length; idx++) {
      if(
        idx == sceneStarts.length-1 && tCur > sceneStarts[idx] ||
        tCur > sceneStarts[idx] && tCur <= sceneStarts[idx+1]
      ){
        annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("seek", sceneStarts[idx]); 
        break;
      }
    }
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Prev. Scene}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("pause");
    try{app.clearInterval(timer);}catch(e){}
    var sceneStarts = [\sceneStarts];
    var tCur=annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("currentTime");
    for(var idx=0; idx < sceneStarts.length-1; idx++) {
      if(tCur >= sceneStarts[idx] && tCur < sceneStarts[idx+1]){
        annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("seek", sceneStarts[idx+1]); 
        break;
      }
    };
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Next Scene}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("pause");
    var sceneStarts = [\sceneStarts];
    %determine current scene
    var tCur=annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("currentTime");
    var curScene = sceneStarts.length-1;
    for(var idx=0; idx < sceneStarts.length-1; idx++) {
      if(tCur >= sceneStarts[idx] && tCur < sceneStarts[idx+1]){
        var curScene = idx;
        break;
      }
    }
    %checks if we are still inside current scene
    var checkScene = function(){
      var tCur=annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("currentTime");
      if(tCur>=sceneStarts[curScene+1]){
        annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("pause");
        annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("seek", sceneStarts[curScene+1]); 
      }
    };
    try{app.clearInterval(timer);}catch(e){}
    if(tCur<sceneStarts[sceneStarts.length-1]){
      var timer=app.setInterval("checkScene()", 200);
    }  
    annotRM["testvideo"].callAS("play");
  }
]{\fbox{\strut Play Scene}}

\end{document}
```